# Is possible to mock locations with Google's new fused location provider?

Tags: android, location, location-provider

Is it possible to get applications such as FakeGPS to work with the new fused location provider (Google Play Services)?

I believe this is the issue:

```
09-20 17:18:41.842  21753-21809/? W/LocationManager﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incomplete location object, missing timestamp or accuracy? Location[gps 32.899542,-100.165065 acc=1 et=?!? alt=65.0]
        at android.location.LocationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.java:1218)
        at com.lexa.fakegps.FakeGPSProvider.run(FakeGPSProvider.java:75)
```

Comment: I would assume that such apps would need to be updated to support feeding mock locations to `LocationClient` [via `setMockMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#setMockMode%28boolean%29) and `setMockLocation()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fused Location Provider can only use mock locations provided by setMockMode() and setMockLocation(). Calling android.location.LocationManager.setTestProviderLocation() has no effect on the locations generated by Fused Location Provider.

Although FakeGPS won't do anything for Fused Location Provider, the new Android training lesson for Mock Locations: [Testing Using Mock Locations](http://developer.android.com/training/location/location-testing.html) includes a sample app that injects mock locations into Fused Location Provider.

Comment: Beware: "Testing Using Mock Locations" uses deprecated class LocationClient.

Comment: "Testing Using Mock Locations includes a sample app that injects mock locations into Fused Location Provider." where?

Comment: They've changed the API. Fused Location Provider is part of Google Play Services. Always subject to change! I wrote the original documentation, which has been removed, which leads me to believe that they changed everything (again).